# markerclusterer click cluster to get child markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using google maps v3 with markerclusterer, working fine, in a jquery mobile web app. I have a listview which I want to populate with the details of all markers within a cluster when clicked, only if that cluster contains 25 or less markers, if there are 26 or more markers I want the default zoom to operate.

I have identified the onclick event in markerclusterer.js where I need to place my code, here...

```
/**
 * Triggers the clusterclick event and zoom's if the option is set.
 *
 * @param {google.maps.MouseEvent} event The event to propagate
 */
ClusterIcon.prototype.triggerClusterClick = function(event) {
  var markerClusterer = this.cluster_.getMarkerClusterer();

  // Trigger the clusterclick event.
  google.maps.event.trigger(markerClusterer, 'clusterclick', this.cluster_, event);

  if (markerClusterer.isZoomOnClick()) {
    // Zoom into the cluster.
    this.map_.fitBounds(this.cluster_.getBounds());
  }

//my code will go here...
//get number of markers in clicked cluster
//if > 25 then zoom as normal
//else get cluster's child markers and loop through to add to listview

};
```

...but is there an easy way of accessing an array of only the markers contained within the cluster clicked, assuming 25 or less markers and if not to zoom as normal.

I can take care of the Listview update ok, but don't know how to isolate the markers for any given cluster...can anyone help? Oh, I have set zoomOnCLick to False in markerclusterer.js, but maybe I should keep this as true and catch clusters with less than 26 markers to update my listview.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem....use the enhanced markerclustererplus.js which has support for a getMarkers() function which can be used to return an array of markers for the clicked cluster using the click event provided

There is also support for a getSize() function which returns the number of markers within the clicked cluster which accounts for my other challenge

Code and examples here...the events example helped in my case

https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclustererplus

Comment: is there any npm package ?